# Akka UDP: "Invalid Argument" when sending to any destination which is not 127.0.0.1

Tags: scala, akka

I use `akka.net.Udp` to send a UDP packet (code below). Sending to my local machine (127.0.0.1) works fine but as soon as I run the same code with another IP address, akka complains "Invalid argument" (output below).

Any ideas what goes wrong?

```
package debug

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorRef, Props}
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import akka.io.{IO, Udp}
import akka.util.ByteString


class SocketTest extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  val dest = new InetSocketAddress("131.179.196.46", 6363)       // Invalid argument
  // val dest = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 6363)         // works fine
  val udp = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[UDP4]), name="udp4")

  // send
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  udp ! (dest, ByteString("hello world"))

  Thread.sleep(99999)
  def receive = {???}

}

class UDP4 extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  val local = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2222)

  import context.system
  IO(Udp) ! Udp.Bind(self, local)

  def receive: Receive = {
    case Udp.Bound(local) => context.become(ready(sender))
  }

  def ready(connection:ActorRef): Receive = {
    case (remote:InetSocketAddress, data:ByteString) => {
      log.info(s"Send to ${remote}: ${data}")
      connection ! Udp.Send(data, remote)
    }
    case Udp.Received(data, remote) => log.info(s"Receive from ${remote}: ${data}")
    case Udp.Unbind => connection ! Udp.Unbind
    case Udp.Unbound => context.stop(self)
  }

}
```

Output with any other destination than local machine:

```
[DEBUG] [06/20/2016 11:54:39.753] [main] [EventStream(akka://Main)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [06/20/2016 11:54:39.754] [main] [EventStream(akka://Main)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [06/20/2016 11:54:39.851] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://Main/system/IO-UDP-FF/selectors/$a/0] Successfully bound to [/127.0.0.1:2222]
[INFO] [06/20/2016 11:54:40.783] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Main/user/app/udp4] Send to /131.179.196.46:6363: ByteString(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100)
[DEBUG] [06/20/2016 11:54:40.789] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://Main/system/IO-UDP-FF/selectors/$a/0] Invalid argument
[DEBUG] [06/20/2016 11:54:40.791] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://Main/system/IO-UDP-FF/selectors/$a/0] Closing DatagramChannel after being stopped
```

Output with 127.0.0.1 as destination:

```
[DEBUG] [06/20/2016 11:55:37.213] [main] [EventStream(akka://Main)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [06/20/2016 11:55:37.214] [main] [EventStream(akka://Main)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [06/20/2016 11:55:37.280] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://Main/system/IO-UDP-FF/selectors/$a/0] Successfully bound to [/127.0.0.1:2222]
[INFO] [06/20/2016 11:55:38.234] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://Main/user/app/udp4] Send to /127.0.0.1:6363: ByteString(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100)
```

Comment: 99% sure you get an IOException with the helpful text "Invalid argument". You'll need to enable finer grained logging and disclose what versions of Akka, OS etc you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the following line:

```
  val local = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2222)
```

It is required to bind not just locally:

```
val local = new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", 2222)
```

After changing this line, the code works as wished.